# Ember: Binding boolean element attribute doesn't work?

Tags: binding, attributes, ember.js

trying to do the boolean "Binding element attributes" thing from the [Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/).

The javascript is:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

window.App.NumberTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  valueChanged: (function() {
    return this.get("controller").set("isNotCompleteId", this.get("value").length !== 6);
  }).observes("value")
});

window.App.LandingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isNotCompleteId: true
});

window.App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.route("landing", {
    path: "/"
  });
});
```

The template is:

```
<h3>Example:</h3>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">    
<p>
    <a href="#"
       {{bindAttr disabled="isNotCompleteId"}}>
         Join number:
    </a>
    {{view App.NumberTextField valueBinding="idEntered" size="8"}}

    <p>{{idEntered}}</p>
</p>

</script>
```

This jsfiddle shows (what I think is the) bad behavior:  http://jsfiddle.net/csterritt/AaTpd/11/

Inspect the "Join number:" link in the Result pane. It doesn't have the "disabled" attribute (I believe it should).  Changing the text in the text box until it has six characters doesn't change the attribute (it should, at six chars).

If I change line 7 of the HTML to {{bindAttr class="isNotCompleteId:foo:bar"}} it works as expected (although the class starts as "bar", and so, the controller attribute starts as false even though I set it to true...???).

Bug?  Confusion on my part?

Thanks!

Comment: NEVER MIND... turns out that Ember is smarter than I am.  Turns out the **a** tag doesn't take a 'disabled' attribute.  Change it to a 'button' and it works perfectly, since 'button' allows a 'disabled' attribute.

Comment: Although, it's worth noting that the **disabled** attribute has to be there in the original HTML if you want it on to begin with.